# Auto-hyperlink certain regex matched text with url with contains matched text result

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How to find certain pattern text on web page and auto hyperlink them.

Want to search text e.g., "**ABCD_12**" or "**ABCD_12_2**" or "**ABCD_12_Q_1**"

All these text should get auto-hyperlinked to documents linked to them = "https://example.com/**ABCD_12**" or "https://example.com/**ABCD_12_2**" or "https://example.com/**ABCD_12_Q_1**"

Need create chrome extension so documents do not need to searched by opening other window.

Any idea how we can do this using javascript.

Thank you

Comment: Use `mark.js` library in your content script.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.